# Tricky question in Matrices!

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, intuition, inverse

Define $$A=[\text{I}+\sum_{k=1}^{m}u_{k}u_{k}^T]^{-1}$$, where for each $u_k$ is a $0-1$ column vector.

Prove that for every $1\leq k \leq m$ $$Au_{k}u_{k}^T\geq0$$ i.e. each entry of $Au_ku_k^T$ is non-negative.

Comment: What does the symbol "$\ge$" mean? The matrix isn't necessarily real symmetric, so it shouldn't mean "positive semidefinite". The matrix is also not necessarily entrywise nonnegative, so the symbol also shouldn't mean "entrywise greater than or equal to".

Comment: I meant it is entrywise greater than or equal to 0. Can you give me an example with negative entries?

Answer (score 3):

A randomly generated example:

Let
$$
U=[u_1,u_2,u_3]=
\begin{bmatrix}
     0  &   1  &   0 \\
     1  &   0  &   0 \\
     1  &   0  &   1 \\
     0  &   0  &   1 \\
     0  &   0  &   0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then
$$
A = (I+UU^T)^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0.5  &       0 &        0 &        0  &       0 \\
         0  &  0.625 &  -0.25 &   0.125  &       0 \\
         0  & -0.25 &   0.5 &  -0.25  &       0 \\
         0  &  0.125 &  -0.25 &   0.625  &       0 \\
         0  &       0 &        0 &        0  &       1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
Au_3u_3^T = 
\begin{bmatrix}
         0   &      0 &        0  &       0   &      0 \\
         0   &      0 &  -0.125  & -0.125   &      0 \\
         0   &      0 &   0.25  &  0.25   &      0 \\
         0   &      0 &   0.375  &  0.375   &      0 \\
         0   &      0 &        0  &       0   &      0 
\end{bmatrix}
\not\geq 0.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I have edited question. Actually I meant elements of $Au_{k}$ where corresponding entry of $u_{k}$ is $1$ is always positive. But I made a mistake in the problem statement. This example does not work in this definition of problem.

Answer (score 2):

Take $u_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$, $u_2=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$, then $A=\frac{1}{5}\begin{bmatrix}2 & -1\\-1& 3\end{bmatrix}$ and $Au_1 u_1^T=\frac{1}{5}\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0\\-1 &0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I have edited question. Actually I meant elements of $Au_{k}$ where corresponding entry of $u_{k}$ is $1$ is always positive. But I made a mistake in the problem statement. This example does not work in this definition of problem.